# How to determine if a self.attribute was defined in __init__()?

Tags: python, class

I want to know if there are any ways to tell that in a class, `if` an `self` attribute is defined in `def.__init__(self)` function.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self.__init__:   #determine whether name is defined in __init__ or no?
           self.__dict__["private_"+name] = value    #if it is, assigned to self.__dict__ with prefixed "private_"+name as a key and value as a value.
        else:    #NameError is raised when assign the same name outside the class if it is already defined in self.__init__,
           raise NameError

O = C()
O.a = 5 # Raise NameError, Because name "a" is defined in __init__ function inside the class C
```

I notice that `self.__init__`  cannot be iterated, so I have no clue how should we tell what is defined in `__init__`.

Comment: You can iterate through `self.__dict__` at any time and see what's currently defined, but not _when_ that occurred (attributes can be added any time).

Comment: Can you explain what you need this for? Since this isn't possible, maybe there is some alternative that can be proposed if we knew what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `name in self.__init__` doesn't work is - as you've noticed - it isn't iterable. It's a function reference.

What you're looking for is `hasattr(self, ...`. This will not specifically check that an attribute has been defined in `__init__`, but it will check that the attribute exists.