# How to find an attribute in self.__init__?

Tags: python, class

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
       if a in self.__init__:  #Determine if a is an instance of __init__ function
           do something
```

The above code will return an error and says

```
    if name in self.__init__:
TypeError: argument of type 'method' is not iterable
```

If I don't iterate through `self.__init__` function, how else am I supposed to know what attributes are defined in `self.__init__` function?

If an attribute is set in `init`, I want to set the name prefixed by `"somestring_"` and append it to `self__dict__`: e.g., if I print `self.__dict__` after `self.__setattr__`, it will print `{'somestring_a': 1, 'somestring_b': 2}`

Comment: `__init__` is analogous to a constructor in other languages. Any properties you set to `self` are available via `self.<property>`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Because if an attribute is set in __init__, I want to set the name prefixed by "somestring_" and append it to self__dict__: e.g., if I print self.__dict__ after self.__setattr__, it will print {'somestring_a': 1, 'somestring_b': 2}

Comment: I might suggest a decorator on init that gave init a proxy object rather than self so it could capture the assignments and map the names.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how things work. Attributes are in no way "inside" a method. They can be set in a method. But you have to keep track of that yourself. You can also do various introspection tricks to get hacks ways to do this. Fundamentally, it just doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: Strangely similar question to [How to determine if a self.attribute was defined in __init__()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580974/how-to-determine-if-a-self-attribute-was-defined-in-init). Are you using two accounts to post questions? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an attribute that lists the attributes that are set in `__init__`, and use that.

```
class C:
    predefined = ['a', 'b']

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if name in self.predefined:
            do something
        else:
            do something else
```

Another option would be to copy the keys of `self.__dict__` at the end of the `__init__` method:

```
class C:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.predefined = set(self.__dict__)

    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        if name in self.predefined:
            do something
        else:
            do something else
```

Comment: If we don't add this list, we couldn't access to what's inside ```self.__init__```?

Comment: You'd need to disassemble the byte code, and find the codes that are assigning to `self.something`. Not easy.

Answer (score 1):

```py
class C():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


a = C(1, 2)
print(a.__dict__)

>>> {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

So `__dict__.keys()` will give you the list of attributes ...

BUT :::

if you will check the list of your attributes in `__setattr__` , you have to keep in mind that this function is also called when you do `a = C(1, 2)` so you shouldn't check your attributes in this level of code.